# Plotting a 3D Polygon Connecting Two Surfaces in Matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, visualization

I'm working on visualizing geological data using matplotlib in Python. I have two irregular surfaces represented as grid data (grid_x, grid_y, grid_z_selected_pick1, grid_z_selected_pick2), and I want to plot a 3D polygon connecting these surfaces.
Interpolated surfaces are defined by:

```
# Defining x and y grids
x_range = max(x_coordinates) - min(x_coordinates)
y_range = max(y_coordinates) - min(y_coordinates)
x_center = (max(x_coordinates) + min(x_coordinates)) / 2
y_center = (max(y_coordinates) + min(y_coordinates)) / 2

grid_x, grid_y = np.meshgrid(np.linspace(x_center - x_range/2, x_center + x_range/2, 100), 
                              np.linspace(y_center - y_range/2, y_center + y_range/2, 100))
                              
# Defining z grid for the first surface
    grid_z_selected_pick1 = griddata((X1, Y1), depth1, (grid_x, grid_y), method='cubic')
    valid_indices1 = ~np.isnan(grid_z_selected_pick1)
    grid_x[~valid_indices1] = np.nan
    grid_y[~valid_indices1] = np.nan
    
    
# Defining z grid for the second surface
    grid_z_selected_pick2 = griddata((X2, Y2), depth2, (grid_x, grid_y), method='cubic')
    valid_indices2 = ~np.isnan(grid_z_selected_pick2)
    grid_x[~valid_indices2] = np.nan
    grid_y[~valid_indices2] = np.nan`
```

Here is my current approach:

- I've plotted the surfaces using `ax.plot_surface`.
- I've extracted the vertices of the surfaces and attempted to connect them to form a polygon using `Poly3DCollection`.
- However, I'm encountering issues with the connectivity between the surfaces, and the resulting plot only shows the polygon of one surface.

`    # Define the vertices of the polygon
polygon_vertices = []

```
# Add vertices for the roof of the polygon (first surface)
for i in range(len(grid_x)):
    for j in range(len(grid_x[0])):
        polygon_vertices.append([grid_x[i][j], grid_y[i][j], grid_z_selected_pick1[i][j]])

# Add vertices for the floor of the polygon (second surface)
for i in range(len(grid_x) - 1, -1, -1):
    for j in range(len(grid_x[0])):
        polygon_vertices.append([grid_x[i][j], grid_y[i][j], grid_z_selected_pick2[i][j]])

# Connect the vertices to form the polygon
polygon_faces = [[i, i + 1, (i + len(grid_x) * len(grid_y) + 1) % len(polygon_vertices), (i + len(grid_x) * len(grid_y)) % len(polygon_vertices)] for i in range(len(grid_x) * len(grid_y))]

# Plot the polygon
polygon_collection = Poly3DCollection([[polygon_vertices[vertex_index] for vertex_index in face] for face in polygon_faces], alpha=0.5, color='blue')
ax.add_collection3d(polygon_collection)`
```

[The attached image shows outputs of this approach](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EzFsp.png)
[Contour maps for each surface](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QrP1G.png)